# Removing GET parameter in .htaccess and get 2 URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this kind of URL:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?page=contest&contest=this-one-contest
```

i'm trying to get 2 functioning urls here.

1. What I'm trying to do is to get this kind of URL:

   http://www.example.com/contest

Which is already done using this htaccess rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

2. What I'm trying to do is to get this kind of URL in the second URL:

   http://www.example.com/contest/this-one-contest

I don't Know if this is even possible using htaccess, and I don't want to create a new folder called "contest".

I have tried this already, but it's not still working.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)contest/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?page=$1&contest=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)contest/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)contest/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a work around that works for me, i made lot's of self tweak to @arkascha solution,

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&contest=$2 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^/?contest/?$ /index.php?contest=1$ [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a 2 step approach, you can immediately rewrite this using a very general approach:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&contest=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This of course assumes that there are no other potential URLs matching the same patterns which you want to handle different ... So if you only want those rules to get applied if the URL starts with `/content/`, then that variant should do:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?contest/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=contest&contest=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?contest/?$ /index.php?page=contest [L,QSA]
```

And of course if that second parameter also is a literal, fixed one you want to react to, then you can get even more specific:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?contest/this-one-contest/?$ /index.php?page=contest&contest=this-one-contest [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?contest/?$ /index.php?page=contest [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It works, but i made lot's of self tweak,
this is what works for me

`RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1&contest=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z_-]+)/$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?contest/?$ /index.php?contest=1$ [L,QSA]`

Comment: Sure, great you found a solution. Note however that the `/$` instead if my `/?$` will only match if there actually is a trailing slash in the request. I would always consider that optional instead, just as I suggested in my answer. And that last rule you added does not have anything to do with what you asked. That appears to be some additional requirement.